# Avoid newline in echo

Tags: powershell

Currently in PowerShell the `echo` command always append a newline. What would be the equivalent for the Unix `echo -n` ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`echo` is an alias for `Write-Output` which sends objects to the next command in the pipeline. If all you want to do is display text on the console you can do:

`Write-Host "Hi" -NoNewLine`

Keep in mind that this is not the same cmdlet as echo|Write-Output.

`Write-Output`'s primary purpose is send objects to the next command in the pipeline where `Write-Host`'s primary purpose is to display text on the console. The reason why you see text on the console using `Write-Output` is that the PowerShell engine sends everything to `Out-Default` at the end of the pipeline which sends the incoming to PowerShell's object to text formatting engine.

Here is an example:

```
Write-Host "hi" | Get-Member
```

This will produce an error because `Write-Host` just writes the text to the console and doesn't forward the string to the next command in the pipeline.

```
Write-Output "hi" | Get-Member
```

This will display the `System.String` properties and methods because `Write-Output` sends the `string` object to the next object in the pipeline.

- `Write-Host`: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347596.aspx
- `Write-Output`: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315282.aspx

Answer (score 8):

You can use `Write-Host`:

```
Write-Host "Hello " -nonewline
Write-Host "There!"
```

Or from the command line:

```
PS C:\> Write-Host "Hello " -nonewline ; Write-Host "There!"
Hello There!
```

Answer (score 7):

To complement [Andy Arismendi's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9280647/45375):

- In Bash, `echo -n` (or its portable equivalent, `printf %s`) sends its arguments to the *data* (output) stream, *stdout*.
- PowerShell's equivalent to the Unix stdout stream is its *success stream*, to which output from commands goes *by default*.
  Note that PowerShell can send objects of any type to the success stream, not just text.
- Therefore, strictly speaking, the equivalent of Bash's `echo -n 'hi'`, for instance, is just `'hi'` in PowerShell - the string is implicitly sent to the success stream.
- That said, **the only way to send a string without a trailing newline to the *console* is to *bypass* the success stream, which is what `Write-Host -NoNewLine`, as discussed in Andy's answer, does**.

  - Up to PowerShell v4, `Write-Host` output couldn't be captured at all, because it simply printed *directly* to the console, bypassing PowerShell's output streams altogether.
  - Since PowerShell v5, `Write-Host` writes to a newly introduced stream for writing structured information, number `6`, and is effectively an alias for
    `Write-Information -InformationAction Continue` - see [`Get-Help Write-Information`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-information).
- When it comes to **writing to *files***, PowerShell **v5** added **support for the `-NoNewline` parameter** to the following cmdlets (up to v4, writing/appending to a text file would *invariably* append a trailing newline), but note that `-NoNewLine` also doesn't place newlines *between* inputs, should there be multiple:

  - `Set-Content` / `Add-Content`
  - `Out-File`

#### Workaround for writing output from multiple commands to a single-line string in the output stream:

The workaround is to simply **use string interpolation or concatenation or formatting** to combine the output from all commands that should form a single line of output text:

For instance, the (rough) equivalent of the following Bash code ...

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo -n 'Today is: '
date
```

... in PowerShell is:

- using an [expandable string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) (string interpolation, inside `"..."`, using subexpression operator `$(...)`):

  ```powershell
  "Today is: $(Get-Date)"
  ```
- alternatively, using *string concatenation*, with operator `+`:

  ```powershell
  'Today is: ' + (Get-Date)
  ```
- or, using `-f`, the (string-)[format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#format-operator--f):

  ```powershell
  'Today is: {0}' -f (Get-Date)
  ```

All these PowerShell commands sends a single-line string to the success stream, but note that this string itself is then invariably followed by a newline when it prints in the *console*.

Comment: @TomaszGandor I've restructured the answer a little to put string interpolation (expandable strings) first, and I've also added use of `-f` as an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

```
Write-Host -n
```

works for me in PowerShell 5.

Comment: PowerShell's elastic syntax allows you to use only the prefix of a parameter name as long as that prefix is unique among all parameters. In your case, `write-host -n` is simply short for `write-host -NoNewLine`, as discussed in the other answers. It's fine to use `-n`, but you should be aware that it may break one day, if another parameter name that starts with `n` is introduced. This is also the reason why you should always use full parameter names in _scripts_.